# Deploying Django app to Heroku: Exception in worker process

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django website to Heroku. I've followed all the steps as well as I could. I created my Procfile, created the Heroku app, set the git remote, and pushed the local changes to the Heroku app.

Seeing my app logs, I saw this error:

```
2021-01-22T10:44:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user **********
2021-01-22T10:45:32.301870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-22T10:45:32.103906+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user *************
2021-01-22T10:45:32.103906+00:00 app[api]: Deploy af87d85b by user *************
2021-01-22T10:45:36.986469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn lessonswithanative.wsgi`
2021-01-22T10:45:39.934947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-22T10:45:39.576978+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-01-22T10:45:39.577706+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48170 (4)
2021-01-22T10:45:39.577813+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-01-22T10:45:39.584050+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:39 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-01-22T10:45:39.595125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:39 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972008+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:40 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972058+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972060+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972061+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972061+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972061+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972062+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972062+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972063+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972063+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972064+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972064+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972064+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972064+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972065+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972065+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972066+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972066+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972067+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972067+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972067+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972068+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972068+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972068+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972069+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lessonswithanative/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972069+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972069+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972070+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972070+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972070+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972071+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972071+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972071+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972072+00:00 app[web.1]:     module = import_module(entry)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972072+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972073+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972073+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972073+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972074+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972081+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herokuapp'
2021-01-22T10:45:40.972495+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:40 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002705+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:40 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002706+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002707+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002708+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002708+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002708+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002709+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002709+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002709+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002710+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002710+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002710+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002711+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002711+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002711+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002711+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002712+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002712+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002713+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002713+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002713+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002713+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002714+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002714+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002714+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/lessonswithanative/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002715+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002715+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002715+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002715+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002716+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002716+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002716+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002716+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002717+00:00 app[web.1]:     module = import_module(entry)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002717+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002717+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002718+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002718+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002718+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-01-22T10:45:41.002765+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herokuapp'
2021-01-22T10:45:41.003496+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:41 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2021-01-22T10:45:41.180396+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-01-22T10:45:41.180603+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-22 10:45:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-01-22T10:45:41.256409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-01-22T10:45:41.288356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-01-22T10:45:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

This is my settings.py file. I'm importing django_heroku and using it as well:

```
from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key_hidden'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['josiahtrotter.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'herokuapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lessonswithanative.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lessonswithanative.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is my folder structure: [image]

Comment: what is **herokuapp** ???

Comment: Why do you have a **herokuapp**, the traceback is telling you **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herokuapp'**